# How to get number, displayed on an external website?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to display some numbers on a website, but they will get updated constantly.
I want to avoid typing them in manually inside the HTML document over and over again.

How can I "grab" for example the "GLOBAL LEADERBOARD" number from the website https://cssbattle.dev/ when I want to use javascript?

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Unless they have a CORS policy, you are not going to do it with JavaScript in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to fetch some data from a website and then display that information in your own site.

You can read data from a URL with the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch). This will allow you to make a request to cssbattle.dev and will result in the html page contained their.

This is unlikely to work however, as the page at cssbattle.dev will likely require some JS to function properly. This means web-scraping is needed.

This is a pretty complex topic for a beginner. I would advise you start out with a simple fetch project - you can use an API from https://apilist.fun/ as a starting point and then move onto more complex parts as you develop your understanding of the basics.

I'm happy to discuss how to get started with this. Leave a comment if so.

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty easy with [This](https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/) [PHP](https://php.net) web scraper.
just use it as

```
<?php
// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');

// This will find all images you can exchange 'img' with any type of html tag like 'a', 'div', etc. 
foreach($html->find('img') as $element){
       echo $element->src . '<br>';
}

// or you can just get an item using its id
$html->find('div#root', 0)->innertext;

// Dump contents (without tags) from HTML
echo file_get_html('http://www.google.com/')->plaintext;
```

It is just for example And it shows the time of New York.

Download the latest version of it from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/files/)